# Tagging collection of urls with multiple remarketing tags via Google tag manager

Tags: google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

We have 50+ discreet urls( ie not all from the same sections) from a domain that need to be tagged into one of 3 audience tags.

I have created :
1. lookup table for each url group.
2 if there is a match with the path it will set the lookup table variable to active.
3. I then have a trigger that will show a tag based on whether that variable is active.

The problem with this solution is that it will only match:
- www.domain.com/webpage
and not
-www.domain.com/Webpage ( ie capitalized url)
-www.domain.com/webpage/ ( ie trailing slash)

Any ideas how to resolve this to match all 3?

Comment: Hi, can you please post your code showing your solution?

Comment: Can't you regex the urls in Tag Manager? Instead of you making it by hand...

Comment: There isn't a clear pattern or folder structure that we can do them all - they are discreet  urls as I said above.  I could maybe put together a group of 5 or so of the tags but it would be harder to do as I would need to exclude other pages from the rule.